# Need to limit Commerce Shipping Condition to only fire if there are no items that do not match

Tags: commerce

We need the condition to trigger only if the cart items match the categories listed and there are no products that do not match.

Is there a way to limit Commerce Shipping Method Conditions (Product->Order Contains Product Categories) to trigger only if the order products match the categories and there none that do not match?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the way that condition was written, it only matches for, "Order contains any products from these categories." The logic you're looking for is, "Order contains *only* products from these categories." For that, you'd need to write a custom condition plugin. This would be a reasonable core feature request for Drupal Commerce and would apply for the other "contains" conditions as well ... which leads me to believe we might implement it as an "operator" select list on the condition itself.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. Yep, I already created the custom condition. It was quite easy, using the core 'order contains categories' condition and modifying.

Comment: @quantumized Oh, nice! Congrats on figuring that out. Does it seem like something you'd want to use to kick off a core feature request that we apply to each of those Order condition types?

Comment: yes, I think it would be a useful feature to have. What do I need to do to 'kick off a core feature request'? Just submit a require in the issue queue? Should I submit a patch with the code too?

Comment: @quantumized Yep! Just open the issue in https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/commerce and feel free to link back to this discussion. A patch as a starting point would be great!